# Determining the interval of convergence of power series.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

So I have this function:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n+3}}(x+1)^n$$

Using ratio test,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}
=  \frac{2^\frac{n+1}{n+4}(x+1)^{n+1}}{2^\frac{n}{n+3}(x+1)^n} =\frac{(n+1)(x+1)}{2^{n+4}2^{\frac{n}{n+3}}}$$

Taking out the constant,

$$(x+1)\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)}{2^{n+4}2^{\frac{n}{n+3}}}$$

Now, how do I even simplify this monster on the right side? :/ Tips will be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You made a mistake with the algebra. The limit is wrong.

Comment: @RyanParikh which part exactly? I can't seem to figure out the wrong part.

Comment: I suppose that the first line is wrong; Could it be $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } 2^{-\frac{n}{n+3}} (x+1)^n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the function I wrote in the first line was the question given, I'm supposed to find the convergence of that

Comment: So, where are coming the fractional powers from ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(x+1)^n}{2^{n+3}}$$

we apply the Ratio Test to find

$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{2^{n+3}(n+1)(x+1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+4}(n)(x+1)^n}\right|=|x+1|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{n+1}{2n}\right|=\frac{|x+1|}{2}$$

therefore the series converges when $|x+1|<2$. That is, when $-3 <x<1$.

---

To verify that the series doesn't converge at $x=1$ and $x=-3$, we evaluate both bounds. At $x=1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n2^n}{2^{n+3}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^3}=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$$

diverges by the divergence test. Similarly, the sum at $x=-3$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(-2)^n}{2^{n+3}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(-1)^n}{2^3}=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn$$

also diverges.

Comment: Plz check both bonds for the being convergence. I think you should add them for making the answer complete. :)

Comment: @mrs: Do you mean that I should add $-2 < x+1 <2$ in order to make the answer complete?

Comment: I mean to take $x=1$ but it into the series and then check it for the result. This way the OP can get your answer better. :-)

Comment: Of course, we have $x=-3$ after that and  the same story as above.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify $\frac{n}{n+3}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{n}}\approx 1$.  So $a_n\approx 2(1+x)^n$  Ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\approx (1+x)$  Therefore converges  for $|1+x|\lt 1$ or $-2\lt x \lt 0$.  Note that $\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{n}} \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: How do I get n/n+3 from the function?

Comment: Thanks, I got it after some tinkering on my own:)